# Java arrays returning all inputs

Tags: java, arrays

In my programming task I need to put several people, and for every single person, except the first, I need to add contacts (every person can choose how many and which contact to choose). I can't use list or maps.

```
Person[] contacts=new Person[Optinal];
//Opitional is an constant
```

In for loop I do this:

```
if (i != 0) {
      // We have more than one person add contacts
    System.out.println("Enter number of contacts: ");
    int noContacts = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();

    if (noContacts < Optinal) {
        for (int k = 0; k < noContacts; k++) {
            contacts[k] = chooseContact(scanner, people, noContancts);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error! ");
    }
}
```

Then in method, I choose which contact I want:

```
 private static Person chooseContact(Scanner scanner, Person[] people, int noContacts){
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.printf("%d. %s %s \n", j+1, people[j].getName(), people[j].getLastName());
    }

    int number = 0;
    do {
        System.out.print("Choose: ");

        while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number!");
            scanner.next();
        }

        broj=scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();

        if (nunber < 0 || number > people.length) {
            System.out.println("Error, enter again");
        }
    } while (number < 0 || number > people.length);
    return people[number-1];
}
```

I enter first person Name: John Last name: Unknown

It skips first person, so John has no contacts

Seconda name: Marry Last name: AlsoUknown

Choose how many contacts u want to choose -> 1
The for loop should present:

1. John Unknown
   Third person Name: Johnny Last:Depp
   How many contacts u want to choose:
   2
   For loop display:
   1.John Unknown
2. Marry AlsoUnknown
   1 -> I choose first person to put into array as contact
   2 -> I choose first person to put into array as contact

The problem is, I can choose only 1 person as contact even if I have several people to choose from.

When I do for loop for `person[i].getContacts().length`, I always get 3 (number of total people I entered as contacts), not number of people I choose as a contact for each individual person.

How can I declare an Object of type `Person[] contacts = new Person(noContacts)` in for loop and properly return it?

Answer (score 0):

length of an array is a constant (your Optinal). It doesn't matter whether INSIDE the array there are null entries, the length is always the same.

Either you need logic to only count the non-nulls, or you can use lists instead of arrays.

Comment: I can't use lists. I need to store several contacts in one person.

Comment: As declared I have 3 people and I put also array of contacts.

Comment: @Qyz93 I am assuming this is homework, otherwise "I can't use lists to store several contacts" makes no sense, that's what a list is for. If you have to use arrays, then for the count you need to check how many entries in the array are non-null. Using length is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

I added Person[] contacts=new Person[0]; before if (i!=0) statement and in for loop contacts=new Person[noContacts];